# C++ Naming Convention for methods / functions that modify parameters and/or return new instance?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, overloading

I would like to know if there's a "widely accepted" naming convention in C++ when writing such methods:

```
class Transform3d {
public: 
    // Apply rotation using a copy of toRotate and return it  
    Vector3d ApplyRotation(const Vector3d& toRotate) const;

    // Apply rotation directly to toRotate 
    void ApplyRotationInPlace(Vector3d& toRotate) const;

    // Apply rotation on this Transform3d instance (orientation quat)
    void ApplyRotation(const Vector3d& toRotate); 

   //...

    // Apply transformation using a copy of toTransform and return it 
    Transform3d ApplyTransform(const Vector3d& toTransform) const;

    // Apply transformation directly to toTransform
    void ApplyTransformInPlace(Vector3d& toTransform) const;

private:
    Quaternion orientation;
    Vector3d position;
};
```

Is there some guidelines for writing C++ method which deals with parameters modification and return new instance (with no modification on the parameter) ?

Comment: Some purists may argue that **Transform3d** should be an immutable class :)

Comment: From the signature it is obvious that `ApplyTransformInPlace` modifies `toTransform` as it takes a non-const reference and returns `void`.  The extra verbiage is just clutter.

Comment: Please drop the `Apply` from your function names, it doesn't add anything. `rotate` and `transform` would convey the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you stumbled upon it. It's the `const` modifiers.

> Is there some guidelines for writing C++ method which deals with
>   parameters modification and return new instance (with no modification
>   on the parameter) ?

By marking your parameters `const`, that's exactly what you guarantee. `const` is really there for the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Its already there in the language itself in your example. Return by value=(new object) pass in const ref=(unmodifiable)  - pass in non const ref=(modifiable).

I would suggest to stay away from decorating method names - because now you have just doubled your code maintenance - by having to alter the function name everywhere every time you decide to change how the function works.